# Finding necessary components from the include statements

Tags: catkin-make, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am reading [this](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/CMakeLists.txt#Finding_Dependent_CMake_Packages) . In order to make a perfect CMakeLists.txt file, we have to supply all the necessary components inside the *find_package* function.

In general, after executing *catkin_create_pkg*, the default CMakeLists file comes with no components and we have to include based on our requirements.

Suppose I am using C++, then I have to include **roscpp** as component inside find. Now if I want to run the new C++ codes for which components I don't know, should I have to guess components form  *#include*  statements of cpp file?

For a given #include statement (say *#include "boost/bind.hpp"*), how to find its components? Is there any way to get all components required by my C++ file without explicitly specifying?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/285186/finding-necessary-components-from-the-include-statements/) by [hagm](https://answers.ros.org/users/33308/hagm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 17 on 2018-03-12

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I hope I can help you to create CMakeLists.txt files for your ROS projects. Please let me know if I miss some information you are looking for.

Firstly, you can specify dependencies when you call `catkin_create_pkg` on the command line so that not only will the components be automatically included in the `find_package` call but the file [package.xml](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/package.xml) will also be updated correctly. If you want to create a new package based on C++, then enter `catkin_create_pkg <your new package name> roscpp` on the command line and **roscpp** will be included in `find_package` automatically. A number of other packages can also be listed at the end of `catkin_create_pkg`, separated by spaces, to include them too. If you want to also include compiled Boost libraries such as **filesystem**, then you enter `catkin_create_pkg -b filesystem<your new package name> roscpp` on the command line.

> Now if I want to run the new C++ codes for which components I don't know, should I have to guess components form #include statements of cpp file?

If you are creating your own ROS project from scratch, you should know which libraries you will be using, but you may not know the CMake components, of which there could be many. When you're going to be using MoveIt, your project will depend on the `moveit_core`, `moveit_msgs`, and `moveit_ros_planning_interface` components. You can see all the components for major ROS libraries at the top of their [wiki page](http://wiki.ros.org/moveit?distro=lunar) as links separated by |. Each component will have its own sub-dependencies too. If you are using someone else's code in your project, you may have to look inside the `#include` statements they use to know which libraries you will depend on; however, the original author should also provide a list of dependencies on GitHub or wherever the code was shared.

Unfortunately, I don't know of any tool that will scan `#include` statements in C++ files to determine appropriate catkin components. I think it would definitely be possible to make such a tool though, and it would be useful!

Finally, you don't have to worry about including certain components, especially Boost libraries like *bind*, explicitly in your CMakeLists.txt because they are most likely included automatically when you specify other components like **roscpp**. I usually add all the components I think I will need to `find_package` then build and see if any errors appear, which will let me know I am still missing a component.

---

Originally posted by [JamesGiller](https://answers.ros.org/users/34047/jamesgiller/) with karma: 229 on 2018-03-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1